# How to stop Eclipse Emulator and Robotium reinstalling apk each time it runs?

Tags: android, eclipse, robotium

or when you reconnect to it.

We are trying to test an app both on and offline.
Sometimes when you change the network state it disconnects the emulator.

We can reconnect to the emulator, but when we run one of the robotium junit test it re-installs the apk.

Is it possible to stop the reinstall of the app?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

If you uninstall the app on the emulator, then reinstall it via robotium junit test.

the next time you run the test, in the console log it will say installing, but this is not the case and it will use the existing app.

(if you install it manually then run the test, the app will be reinstalled.)